# Bluetooth SPP receive some the package frame can lost or?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I use android sample code to modify. Only want to receive package
but, my code only modify here

```
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
            if(D) Log.i(TAG, "MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: " + msg.arg1);
            switch (msg.arg1) {
            case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED:
                mTitle.setText(R.string.title_connected_to);
                mTitle.append(mConnectedDeviceName);
                mConversationArrayAdapter.clear();
                break;
            case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTING:
                mTitle.setText(R.string.title_connecting);
                break;
            case BluetoothChatService.STATE_LISTEN:
            case BluetoothChatService.STATE_NONE:
                mTitle.setText(R.string.title_not_connected);
                break;
            }
            break;
        case MESSAGE_WRITE:
            byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            // construct a string from the buffer
            String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);
            mConversationArrayAdapter.add(writeMessage);
            break;
        case MESSAGE_READ:

            byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
            //String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
            //String readMessage = BytesTrans_fill.bytesToHexString(readBuf);
            Log.d("read", BytesTrans.bytes2HexString(readBuf,msg.arg1));
            String readMessage = BytesTrans.bytes2HexString(readBuf,msg.arg1);
            ppV.setText(ppV.getText().toString() + readMessage + "★");
            break;
        case MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME:
            // save the connected device's name
            mConnectedDeviceName = msg.getData().getString(
                    DEVICE_NAME);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected to "
                           + mConnectedDeviceName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case MESSAGE_TOAST:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg.getData().getString(TOAST),
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

and BluetoothChatService

```
    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        int bytes;

        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                connectionLost();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

and add this function

```
package com.example.android.BluetoothChat;

public class BytesTrans {
    public static String byte2HexString(byte b) {
        String ret = "";
            String hex = Integer.toHexString(b & 0xFF);
            if (hex.length() == 1) {
                hex = '0' + hex;
            }
            ret += hex.toUpperCase()  + " ";
        return ret;
    }

    public static String bytes2HexString(byte[] b, int count) {
        String ret = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            String hex = Integer.toHexString(b[i] & 0xFF);
            if (hex.length() == 1) {
                hex = '0' + hex;
            }
            ret += hex.toUpperCase() + " ";
        }
        return ret;
    }
    /*public static String String2byte(String b)
    {
        String[] ttt;
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++)
        {
            for (int j= i; j<=i+1; j++)
            {
                ttt[i] = b;
            }

        }           

        String ttmp = "";
        String tmp = "";





        ret += tmp;
    }*/
    public static int hexToTen(String b) {
        int D2 = Integer.parseInt(b,16);


        return D2;
        }
    }
```

but this program to show sometime not even to my send package's frame

i send package like this:

aa07210820001202140934390000000000000000000000000000000000000000000297c0fe6b

but sometime receive package:

aa000297c0fe6b02131452470000000000000000000000000000000000000000000297c0fe6b

how can I to change my code to receive complete package's frame

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is very detail. Because this only use bluetoothChat example, so I only paste modify place. and I don't understand, why this code can produce this problem. I am not search this bug until now. Can you give me some teach?? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't shown any of your Bluetooth interface code. However, if this is based heavily on the BluetoothChat example, then there is a simple problem with the BluetoothChat example as it stands: Basically, when a `read()` is made from the Bluetooth socket and put into a byte array, that array reference is sent across to the UI using a `Handler`, as you are doing. The actual problem is that if the BluetoothChat example is used to receive data at a speed of anything faster than typing rate, then you start to see characters go missing or become jumbled because a subsequent `read()` is overwriting the array while the UI is still reading the array to extract the last bunch of characters received.

So, if your `MESSAGE_WRITE` object contains a reference to the array you're making socket `read()` calls into, then this is possibly why you're losing characters. Therefore, try sending a *copy* of the array, using `Arrays.copyOf()`, in the `Message`. Or, perhaps there's a circular buffer arrangement you could use.

I had exactly this problem when I used the BluetoothChat example as the basis for my project. What I personally did to get around the problem (and to eliminate the need for copying buffers, etc.) was to implement a mechanism whereby I would tell the Bluetooth connection thread (the thread that contains the blocking socket `.read()`), by means of a method call, how many bytes I expect the response to be (fortunately, the protocol I'm dealing with allows the response length to be known). The connection thread then only sends a `Message` when the complete response is received, instead of sending several `Message`s with fragments of the response to the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, using the Android Chat sample code. It is only a possible solution. I'm receiving messages ended by `\n`. I'm using this thread to read messages from an Arduino connected by Bluetooth. On the Arduino, I can ensure that every message is ended by `\n`, using `Serial.println( buffer );`.

Everything I received is appended to an existing string (`queue` variable). When I have a entire line on this large string, I send it to the activity and remove it from the `queue` variable.

```
    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes, pos;
        StringBuilder queue = new StringBuilder("");
        String temp;
        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
        while (true) {
            try {
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                if (bytes > 0) {
                    String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                    queue.append(readMessage);
                    pos = queue.indexOf("\n");
                    while (pos >= 0) {
                        // Log.d("Temperatura", "indexOf() #" + pos);
                        temp = queue.substring(0, pos - 1);
                        queue.delete(0, pos + 1);
                        mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_READ, 0, 0, temp).sendToTarget();
                        pos = queue.indexOf("\n");
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                connectionLost();
                // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                BluetoothChatService.this.start();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```