# Bluetooth getInputStream gets multiple/splitted Datapackages?

Tags: android

i'm using the Infamous BluetoothChat-Example from Google to receive a ByteArray.
I know his length (55bytes), his Start Byte (0x69) and his End Byte (0x16) as well as the length of the data in the Array.

I'm quite sure that the Sender sends out 55 Bytes without any interruption but on the BluethootChat Example it looks like i receive multiple data packages.
The first package consists of 0x69 followed by 1023 times 0x00.
Then i receive the rest of the 55bytes.
This happens 70% of the time, sometimes the array get spiltted in the middle and sometimes the whole array is received complete.

Is this a normal Android-Bluetooth behavior

Thanks in advance...

```
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread");
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
        }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes;

        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                connectionLost();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270965/bluetooth-spp-receive-some-the-package-frame-can-lost-or) answered the same question. I just had a same issue and this answer was what I found.

Comment: i tried it with a copy of the array ..not working :(
did you managed to get a solution ?

Comment: My application sends short message so it is not a problem for me. You should looked at the last paragraph for the solution. The copy of array is a suggestion he did not try himself, yet the last paragraph told you how did he solve the problem.